# Cannot serialize/deserialize DateTime to JSON

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, jodatime

I'm struggling with this one for few hours now, and I have found myself in dead end. Everything seems to be set as in other stack questions and tutorials, but `DateTime` object won't serialize anyways. What am I missing?

I already set `JodaModule()`, and I also disabled `ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE` for a moment in mapper, because current error is: `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE`, but that didn't helped.

Simplified code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModules(new JodaModule());

Book newBook = new Book();
newBook.setCreationtime(new DateTime());

String convertedBook = null;
    try {
        convertedBook = mapper.writeValueAsString(newBook);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

gradle:

```
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'
compile files('libs/jackson-datatype-joda-2.9.4.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.9.5.jar')
```

Edit:
After a while, I am pretty sure that problem is in `Book.class`:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.JodaModule;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModules(new JodaModule());


        try {
            Book newBook = new Book();
            newBook.setId(10);
            newBook.setCreationtime(new DateTime());

            String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(newBook);
            Book newBook2 = mapper.readValue(json, Book.class);
            String result = newBook2.getId() + ", " + newBook2.getCreationtime();
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @JsonPropertyOrder({
        "id",
        "creationtime"
    })
    public static class Book implements Serializable {

        @JsonProperty("id")
        private Integer id;
        @JsonProperty("creationtime")
        private DateTime creationtime;

        @JsonProperty("id")
        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        @JsonProperty("id")
        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @JsonProperty("creationtime")
        public DateTime getCreationtime() {
            return creationtime;
        }

        @JsonProperty("creationtime")
        public void setCreationtime(DateTime creationtime) {
            this.creationtime = creationtime;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not very clear what problem you're facing. Please provide a [mcve] and show your input, output and expected output.

Comment: Show us the contents of your `Book` class in a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. When you call `setCreationtime(new DateTime())` are you actually storing the value in a way that can be serialized?

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Ok, I have provided minimal example. I'm pretty sure I'm storing `DateTime` object incorrect in `Book.class`, since I can serialize standalone `DateTime` objects to JSON.

Comment: Just a guess.  Try using `@JsonProperty` on either the fields or the getters and setters.